# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timestamp' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am new to hightcharts, I have an error which I found it on chrome console. And the error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timestamp' of undefined". Below is my code:

**Javascript.JS:**

```
if(selVal==str2[j]) {
    console.log("FOLDERNAME"+selVal);
    str3.push(str2[j+1]);
}

var json = str3[0];

**//This is for highcharts where I am trying to load myjson that is present in "var json"**
for (var k = 0; k < json.length; k++) {
    jsonArray.push({
    name: json[k].map.timestamp,**//Getting error over here**
    y:json[k].map.count
});
```

**JSON FORMAT:**

```
[{"map":{"timestamp":"2016-01-09 05:55:42.0","count":367}}]
```

Somebody please help me out in solving this. I almost tried everything.

Comment: Please format properly your question. It will increase your chances to get an answer. You can also review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It seems that you try to get properties from string, just [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) json string first. [Check example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CJPM4wFHN9FGl4x65U5r)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please give us more codes to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var json=[{"map":{"timestamp":"2016-01-09 05:55:42.0","count":367}}];

/***This is for highcharts where I am trying to load myjson that is present in "var json"**/
var jsonArray=[];
for (var k = 0; k < json.length; k++) {
    jsonArray.push({
    name: json[k]["map"].timestamp,
    y:json[k]["map"].count
    });
}
console.log(jsonArray)
```